# Bathroom Fan with Humidity Sensor Wiring Question

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom

I just purchased a new fan for a bathroom with an in-fan humidity sensor.  [Here's the installation manual](https://aeropurefans.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Installation-Manual-AP-90-120-S-and-H-S-Combined.pdf).

The fan has 6 wires coming out of it: 2 black, 2 white, 1 brown, and ground; the brown is labeled 'for humidity sensor or speed control'.  Am I going crazy or does the wiring diagram on p.3 of the manual suggest that you need two switches for this: one for the fan and one for the humidity sensor?  This seems a weird set up because I can see my kids repeatedly flipping the useless switch that apparently does nothing (i.e., the humidity sensor switch!) to get the thing to work.  Two questions:

- Any ideas on whether this must be wired with two switched?
- If not, do you think everything could be wired to one switch and everything still work?

I've tried contacting the manufacturer and it seems that customer support is non-existent smh...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the fan and humidity sensor can be switched independently to give you a choice of operational modes. Switching on the humidity sensor gives it control of fan cycle. Switching on the fan directly overrides that mode.

> The humidity control and fan can be operated separately. Use a 1- or 2- function wall control. Do not use a dimmer switch
>   to operate the humidity control.

You can connect the brown to a switch or you can connect it directly to the hot conductor to have the humidity sensor operate full-time. It doesn't really matter as long as both blacks and the brown from the fan unit have power when you want it to run.